# How to call ./snowsql file from a bash script on Mac?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to make a connection from a bash script, accomplishing something similar to this:

```
rmcguigan$ snowsql --filename test.sql
* SnowSQL * v1.1.86
Type SQL statements or !help
+----------------+                                                              
| GREATEST(1, 2) |
|----------------|
|              2 |
+----------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.108s
```

So I am running a bash file with chmod 755

```
>./test.sh
```

This is the contents of the file
    ./snowsql test.sql

```
syslog -s -l "Good to go"
```

results

```
rmcguigan$ ./test.sh ./test.sh: line 3: ./snowsql: No such file or
directory Unknown level: Good to go
```

How should my bash script call ./snowsql test.sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you have `./snowsql test.sql` in your `test.sh` file, which tries to find and execute a file named `snowsql` in the current directory rather than running the command with that name. Try removing the `./` and using the `--filename` argument so that the file looks like this:

```sh
snowsql --filename test.sql
```

Make sure that you have a file named `test.sql` in your current directory as well with whatever SQL statement you want to execute.